# Optimize sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I'm trying to optimize sql query which now takes about 20s to execute.

Here is the structure of my tables.

```
last_login

id | ip_address |when
1    2130706433 2012-05-04 12:00:36
```

and

```
country_by_ip

ip_from | ip_to | country
16843008 | 16843263 | CN
```

Here is the query I use:

```
SELECT 
ll.ip_address,
ll.when,
cbi.country
FROM last_login ll
LEFT JOIN `country_by_ip` cbi on ll.ip_address BETWEEN  cbi.ip_from AND cbi.ip_to
```

The fields ip_from and ip_to are indexed.

Can you recommend me how to speed up this query ?

//EDIT

```
CREATE TABLE `last_login` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip_address` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `when` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `country_by_ip` (
  `ip_from` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ip_to` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `ip_from` (`ip_from`),
  KEY `ip_to` (`ip_to`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

[image: EXPLAIN EXTENDED]

Comment: Please show us the table structures, as given by `SHOW CREATE TABLE last_login` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE country_by_ip`. Also, would be useful to see what `EXPLAIN EXTENDED <your_query>` gives. I suspect the `LEFT JOIN` based on a `BETWEEN` clause is a badass performance killer.

Comment: How large (in terms of number of rows) are these tables? What is the clustered index on `country_by_ip`?

Comment: @AdamRobinson, last_login have 31 records. country_by_ip have 116288 records.

Comment: @din2: please also post the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`. You probably need to replace your indexes on `ip_from` and `ip_to` with a single index on both.

Comment: Bonus question: can you change the DB schema in any way, or are you bound to it?

Comment: I have added a screenshot. Please check it now.

Comment: @Romain, no problem to change the DB schema.

Comment: @din2: If possible, I'd like to have (full) table content fo both tables in a pastebin/gist/whatever... Getting `LEFT JOIN` and `BETWEEN` using indices is... Tricky.

Comment: @Romain here http://www.2shared.com/document/waizMTzz/dump.html is dump of both tables.

Comment: So, I've imported your dump in MySQL 5.5.20, did not change anything, and I was able to run your query in 4.57 seconds, resulting in 31 lines. Maybe your server is just out of processing resources or memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT 
ll.ip_address,
ll.when,
cbi.country
FROM last_login ll
LEFT JOIN `country_by_ip` cbi on ll.ip_address > cbi.ip_from 
WHERE ll.ip_address < cbi.ip_to
```

However, I am totally agree with @Romain, change the DB schema to better design.

Comment: Thanks !
The query not tooks just 544ms

Comment: The `where` clause like this essentially makes your join an inner join. This is equivalent to the original query with a normal `join` instead of a `left join`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing yourself any favours by splitting the country_by_ip range across 2 sperate indexes - change these to KEY `ip_range` (`ip_from`,`ip_to`).